# Data structure for array of string arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I checked other questions and googled as well but didn't find a proper answer according to my demand.

This is web app and I am using a rest service. I have a class `Request` and it has an attribute `RequestedAttrbs`. User have to send `RequestAttrbs` and their values in request and i have to store them.

Now user can provide:

```
id: 123
marks: 12, 13, 14
```

Problem is user can provide multiple attributes and can provide multiple values for each attribute. Which data structure will be best to handle this?
I am new to java and want to solve this problem.

Waiting for your positive reply.

Comment: Try `Map<Integer,Set<Integer>` where `123` is key and `[12,13,14]` is value

Comment: But my key and value both must be string

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a normal [`Map<String, List<String>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) type, for example:

```
String key = "keyValue";
String value1 = "value1";
String value2 = "value2";
String value3 = "value3";

Map<String, List<String>> requestAttrbs1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

if (!requestAttrbs1.containsKey(key)) {
    requestAttrbs1.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
}
requestAttrbs1.get(key).add(value1);
requestAttrbs1.get(key).add(value2);
requestAttrbs1.get(key).add(value3);

requestAttrbs1.get(key).remove(value2);

for (String value : requestAttrbs1.get(key)) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Alternatively, if you can use libraries you might want to look at the [`MultiValueMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html) in [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/):

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> requestAttrbs2 = new MultiValueMap<String, String>();

requestAttrbs2.put(key, value1);
requestAttrbs2.put(key, value2);
requestAttrbs2.put(key, value3);

requestAttrbs2.removeMapping(key, value2);

for (String value : requestAttrbs2.getCollection(key)) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Both code snippets will print out:

```
value1
value3
```

As you can see the `MultiValueMap` version is slightly shorter, saving you the trouble of checking whether the key already exists and explicitly getting the list out yourself.

Comment: can you please explain it with example that how i will add or remove things?